# Remove external borders from sections on a single page website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single page website and I have a problem with it, I have added sections to it and whenever a link is clicked within that page it goes to that particular section and when it goes I see external borders covering that section and they go when I click anywhere on the page. How can I remove those annoying boxes around the content?

Comment: Will help us with your code, what did you try until now

Comment: Plz. share your code

Comment: use outline:none to remove default border.

Or please share code, screenshot so that people can help you out

Comment: Hey, thanks for reverting back. You can check the website here https://gloobert.com. The whole website is having that issue.

Comment: I have tried border:none and outline:none css properties and they don't seem to work

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it with css.
Exaple you section class name is .mysection
you add a line to the css

```
.mysection:focus{
   outline: none;
}
.mysection{
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues with that website - but the cause of the outline on navigation is the line as follows:

```
$target.focus();
```

If you remove that - it should remove the line - If you find out why that is there - replace the logic. It looks very funky - and not the good kind of funky.